# ASP.NET MVC Route with dash

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got ASP.NET MVC routing question.

I prepared following routing table to map such url

> mywebsite/mycontroller/myaction/14-longandprettyseoname

to parameters:

> 14 => id (integer)
>
> longandprettyseoname -> seo_name (string)

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "myname",
        "mycontroller/myaction/{id}-{seo_name}", 
        new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", id = 0, seo_name = (string)null });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",  
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

It works for URL above but it has problems for following type of urls

> mywebsite/mycontroller/myaction/14-long-and-pretty-seo-name

Is that possible to make it working?

---

**EDIT:**

`"mycontroller/myaction/{seo_name}-{id}"`

seems to be working

Comment: would a simpler solution be to have url's such as mywebsite/mycontroller/mycation/14/long-and-pretty-seo-name like stack overflow does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the route will be distinguishable as it will not be able to figure which "-" to split at to specify the `{id}` and the `{seo-name}`.

How about using *underscores* for your SEO name?  Or you could just use the SEO name as the actual `{id}`. If the SEO name is something that is going to be unique, this is a very viable option you can use as a pseudo primary key to that entry in your db (assuming it's pulling something from a DB)

Also, utilize Phil Haack's [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what works and doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want seo_name to be globally unique so this is a reason of placing id field at the begininning.
If it cannot distinguish dashes then I can change rule to mycontroller/myaction/{id}/{seo_name} and for me it's ok but I don't know if it violates any seo rules / best-practices

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do this is to use constraints.

Since that your id is an integer, you can add a constraint which will look for an integer value:

```
new { id = @"\d+" }
```

and here is the whole route:

```
routes.MapRoute("myname","mycontroller/myaction/{id}-{seo_name}", 
        new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction" }, 
        new { id = @"\d+"});
```

Comment: You'd think this would work. But it doesn't work. At least, not for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is define route as:

```
routes.MapRoute("myname","mycontroller/myaction/{id}",  
        new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction"});
```

and parse id and seoname manualy using Regex in HTTP handler:

```
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match((string)routeData.Values["id"], @"^(?<id>\d+)-(?<seoname>[\S\s]*)$");
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "Bad Request";
            return;
        }

        int id = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["id"].Value);
        string seoname = match.Groups["seoname"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a specific route such as:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "TandC", // Route controllerName
            "CommonPath/{controller}/Terms-and-Conditions", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Terms_and_Conditions" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

But this route has to be registered **BEFORE** your default route.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is create a custom controller factory. That way you can have custom code to decide which controller needs to be called when.

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        #region IControllerFactory Members

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerName");

            //string language = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"];
            //can be used to translate controller name and get correct controller even when url is in foreign language

            //format controller name
            controllerName = String.Format("MyNamespace.Controllers.{0}Controller",controllerName.Replace("-","_"));

            IController controller = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(controllerName)) as IController;
            controller.ActionInvoker = new CustomInvoker(); //only when using custominvoker for actionname rewriting
            return controller;
        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            if (controller is IDisposable)
                (controller as IDisposable).Dispose();
            else
                controller = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

To use this custom controllerfactory, you should add this in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));
        }
```

Note that this only works for the controller, not for the actions... To hook up custom rewriting on actions before they get executed, use this code:

```
public class CustomInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    #region IActionInvoker Members

    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
    {
        return base.InvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName.Replace("-", "_"));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I got most of this code from [this blog](http://nayyeri.net/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc) and adjusted it to my needs. In my case, I want dashes to separate words in my controller name but you can't create an action with a dash in the name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you downvote my answer it would be nice to explain why, so I know what is wrong.